# What is the difference between Checkstyle and FindBugs?

Tags: debugging, plugins, code-analysis, checkstyle, findbugs

what is the main difference between CheckStyle and FindBugs code analyzer plugin for Eclipse IDE.I need advantage and disadvantage for both the plugins.

Comment: What do you want to decide, based on the information you get here? Whether to use them at all? Or fitness for a particular purpose? If so, which purpose?

Comment: What have you found so far ? Did you even read some articles ?
https://www.google.com/search?q=checkstyle+vs+findbugs

https://www.reddit.com/r/java/comments/3i7w6n/checkstyle_vs_pmd_vs_findbugs_for_dummies_why/

Answer (score 3):

The main difference is that checkstyle runs against source code, and findbugs runs against bytecode. This dictates in many ways the types of bugs that can be found with each. For instance FindBugs could not find where you used tabs instead of spaces. However, the more complex a detector is, including how many classes it has to pull in to check the pattern you are after, the more likely it is easier to do in findbugs.